# Efficient nearest neighbor search for a specific task?

Tags: python, algorithm, spatial, nearest-neighbor

I am looking for an implementation of a nearest neighbor search in 3D.

I am currently using scipy.spatial. The problem is that I need to update the tree/index very often and it seems like with this implementation the tree is rebuilt each time I need to update it, resulting in very long execution times.

The task that I'm trying to solve is as follows: **for a large set of 3D points, unite the points that are too close to each other (closer than the specified gap value).**

I currently solve this by looping through the list of points, adding a new point to the index if it doesn't have any too-close neighbors, and assigning to the point the coordinates of a neighbor if one is found.

I'd be grateful for any other quick alternatives to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

For fast nearest neighbor search I can recommend flann (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN). For pointclouds I would try the PCL (http://pointclouds.org/). Both have python bindings.

One idea would be to cluster the points with the PCL and unite the clusters for example. (segmentation.html">http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group_segmentation.html)

Comment: Will look into it, thanks. I'm thinking about implementing some sort of an Octree though.